# Checking for missing rows in pandas dataframe based on subsetting columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes from two sources that should be the same.

I would like to iterate through a subset of each column combination to get a count of the number of different rows between each dataframe.

Right now I can do it manually, but I would like to write a function or script that can automate this for me. Any ideas?

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [3, 4, 6], 'col3': [3, 4, 7]}
d1 = {'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [3, 4, 6], 'col3': [3, 4, 3]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
```

Check all rows:

```
merged = df.merge(df1, indicator=True, how='outer')
rows_missing_from_df = merged[merged['_merge'] == 'right_only']
rows_missing_from_df.shape

(1, 4)
```

Check rows for just col1 and col2

```
df_select = df[['col1', 'col2']]
df1_select = df1[['col1', 'col2']]

merged = df_select.merge(df1_select, indicator=True, how='outer')
rows_missing_from_df = merged[merged['_merge'] == 'right_only']
rows_missing_from_df.shape

(0, 3)
```

Check rows for just col2 and col3

```
df_select_1 = df[['col2', 'col3']]
df1_select_1 = df1[['col2', 'col3']]

merged = df_select_1.merge(df1_select_1, indicator=True, how='outer')
rows_missing_from_df = merged[merged['_merge'] == 'right_only']
rows_missing_from_df.shape

(1, 3)
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I think a dictionary with the key as a list of the subset of columns used, and the value as the number of missing rows.